# .htaccess rewrite in subdirectory not working under root directory with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My domain points to root folder. In this folder I need to have .htaccess which will redirect to subfolder.

In the root folder I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/folder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) /sub/folder/$1 [L]
```

In sub/folder/.htaccess I have this lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?action=404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image/([^/]+)/(\d+)x(\d+)/([^/]+).(jpg|png)$
RewriteRule (.*) file.php?action=%1&code=%4&w=%2&h=%3 [B,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cscard_valid$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?action=cscardvalid&ajax=true [L,QSA]
..
```

I don't known why redirects doesn't works. Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: (1) Make sure you `AllowOverride All` (2) Shouldn't the rewrite base be `/sub/folder` in the subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `.htaccess` in the subfolder then add rules to your root one like so:

```
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+)/(\d+)x(\d+)/([^/]+).(jpg|png)$ sub/folder/file.php?action=$1&code=$4&w=$2&h=$3 [B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: And is there any possibility to Setup root to /sub/folder/?

This works, but for everything I need htacess lines. I have the url like /userfiles/ in html and this not working.

Thanks

Comment: You can resolve any virtual URL to any physical file. Look at the example I gave and apply it to your other URLs. If you want to match the request to the web root, the pattern would be `^(?:$|\?)`

Comment: The target of your default `RewriteRule` would be `sub/folder/index.php` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Because if your "sub" htaccess is in the web uri `/subfolder`, then it's impossible for it to be triggered by requests for `/image` or `/cscard_valid`. Those are DIFFERENT directories. Apache only scans url-listed directories for htaccess files, and won't go into "parallel" or "neighbor" directories.

e.g., for a url `/foo/bar/baz`, Apache will check for the following:

```
/foo/.htaccess
/foo/bar/.htaccess
/foo/bar/baz/.htaccess
```

If you have a .htaccess file in `/foo/himom`, that's irrelevant. It's not in the path for the requested file, so it never gets scanned for.

Comment: But my "sub" htaccess is under correct subfolder.

Root folder: /var/www/domain/

and "sub" htaccess is there: /var/www/domain/sub/folder

Comment: yes, but you're doing `RewriteCond` for paths than can never appear in your folder.  If the request is coming into `/sub/folder/whatever`, then it's impossible for the request uri to be `/image/kittens.jpg`

Comment: So what to do? Is there any possibility to get it works? 

Move all from "sub" htaccess to root htaccess and replace something? 

Thanks

Comment: look. if you're trying to watch a train go by, you go stand by the rail tracks. you don't go stand by a dirt road and wonder why you never see any trains. If you want to rewrite your image requests, then the .htaccess stuff has to be in the `/images` directory.

Comment: Every request are moved to index.php. Image path in URL is only part of URL, the image folder doesn't exists on the disk.

Comment: yes, but you've also got `^/image`, which means the request uri has to start with `/image`. you're not doing a client-side redirect, so request_Uri is what the client sent over, which would be `http://example.com/sub/folder`, making %{REQUEST_URI} `/sub/folder`

Comment: Ok .. so what now? I copy here summary: Once more and more clearly. The subfolder contains web application, where everything is redirected over index.php. In this subfolder (for application root) is .htaccess with all rewriteRules.

But the URL not directed in this folder, but his parent (parent parent). So in this parent folder I have redirect to subfolder.

It is understandable? The /image/ in the subfolder is only part of URL, no existing folder. Thanks.

Comment: no, not really clear. Put some sample urls in your question. What you see in the browser, what gets sent to the server,etc..

Comment: this was very helpfull @Marc B, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you do not need the .htaccess in the /sub/folder/, only the one in the root. And the contents of it should look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image/([^/]+)/(\d+)x(\d+)/([^/]+).(jpg|png)$
RewriteRule (.*) sub/folder/file.php?action=$1&code=$4&w=$2&h=$3 [B,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cscard_valid$
RewriteRule (.*) sub/folder/index.php?action=cscardvalid&ajax=true [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*) sub/folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still not working, when I move on /image/category/120x165/5210.jpg eg, I'm not redirected :(

Comment: Is the `image` folder inside `/sub/folder/`? Maybe you can tell us more of what are you trying to achieve by this `/` => `/sub/folder/` redirect?

Comment: Once more and more clearly. The subfolder contains web application, where everything is redirected over index.php. In this subfolder (for application root) is .htaccess with all rewriteRules.

But the URL not directed in this folder, but his parent (parent parent). So in this parent folder I have redirect to subfolder.

It is understandable? The /image/ in the subfolder is only part of URL, no existing folder. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Edited my answer.